Need to locate XPath for label element (which is not interactable in UI)
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="padding-left: 0px; margin-top: -4px !important;" xpath="1">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="custom-control-input" value="true" id="__BVID__6418">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__6418"> ::before ::after </label>
</div>

Here I need to select label ::after element, but when I select that in selector hub it says

Alert: This element is not interactable through selenium(automation) as it is not visible in UI. Try any near by element.

What can I do in this issue? How can I locate that label ::after?
here div is parent of both input and label elements
Tried to locate ::after in label element, but it say element is not interactable in ui , how to overcome this issue and how to locate that ::after in label element?

Try //label[contains(.,"::after")]/parent::div

You can get the element's .text() which will grab the rendered text in the pseudo-element.

not working, can i able to locate pseudo element ?

Does this answer your question? Click on pseudo element using Selenium

::before and ::after are inside of the element.  They're basically text nodes in there.  They are immediate children of that element.  So  is the element... that element's .text() method will return the rendered text.  (I say rendered because it's not really in the DOM, it's the result of a stylesheet being processed.)
